# Debugging a simple collision processor

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging, collision

My method of processing collision is to divide the velocity vector into two components, normal axis and tangent axis, tangent axis is perpendicular two the normal axis. Normal axis is parallel to the line that connects the centers of two objects.

Then I convert the normal vector component of the velocity component to momentum.

`Momentum = Velocity * Mass.`

Then I pass the momentum of object A to B, and B to A.

Then I find corresponding velocity for A and B based on the momentum exchanged and unchanged velocity at the tangent axis.

Seems reasonable to me, and it works!

But the thing is it sometimes gets an error.

I use Visual Studio.

I do know little bit about debugging tool, but unable to utilize it well to find the glitch.

Please, I would deeply appreciate if someone could help it.

This is my 4th time writing the whole code from the scratch.

But this same method gets the error always.

So I start to write the whole thing from the scratch hoping that I could somehow fix it by organizing. Please... help.

```
class Vector
{

    public double X = 0;
    public double Y = 0;
    public double Z = 0;
    public Vector direction
    {
        get { return new Vector(0.00000001 + X / Math.Abs(X), 0.00000001 + Y / Math.Abs(Y), 0.00000001 + Z / Math.Abs(Z)); }
    }

    public double angle { get { return Math.Atan2(Y, Z); } }

    //scholar operation
    public static Vector operator + (Vector v1 , double s) {
        return new Vector(v1.X + s , v1.Y + s , v1.Z +s );
    }
    public static Vector operator -(Vector v1, double s)
    {
        return new Vector(v1.X - s, v1.Y - s, v1.Z - s);
    }
    public static Vector operator *(Vector v, double s)
    {
        return new Vector(v.X * s, v.Y * s, v.Z * s);
    }
    //vector to vector operation
    public static Vector operator +(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        return new Vector(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y, a.Z + b.Z);
    }
    public static Vector operator -(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        return new Vector(a.X - b.X, a.Y - b.Y, a.Z - b.Z);
    }
    public static Vector operator *(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        return new Vector(a.X * b.X, a.Y * b.Y, a.Z *b.Z);
    }
    //other operations
    public static Vector operator %(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        return new Vector(a.Y*b.Z - a.Z*b.Y, a.Z*b.X - a.X*b.Z , a.X*b.Y - a.Y*b.X);
    }
    public static double dotProduct(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        Vector v = a*b;
        return a.X + a.Y + a.Z;
    }
    public static void makeOrthonormalBasic(Vector a, Vector b, Vector c)
    {
        c = b % a;
        if (c.squareMagnitude() != 0)
        {
            a = c % b;
        }
    }

    public Vector()
    {
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
        Z = 0;
    }
    public Vector(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
    public Vector (double x , double y )
    {
        X= x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void flip()
    {
        X *= -1;
        Y *= -1;
        Z *= -1;
    }
    public Vector fliped_vector()
    {
        Vector v = new Vector(X * -1, Y * -1, Z * -1);
        return v;
    }
    public double magnitude()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);            
    }
    public double squareMagnitude() {
        return X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z;
    }
    public Vector normalize()
    {
        double m = magnitude();
        if (m > 0)
        {
            Vector v = new Vector();
            v.X = this.X;
            v.Y = this.Y;
            v *= 1 / m;
            return v;
        }
        return new Vector() ;
    }

    public void zero()
    {
        X = 0;
        Y = 0;
    }
    public void set(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public void add(double x, double y)
    {
        X += x;
        Y += y;
    }

}

class KCircle
{
    double size = 30;
    #region instant variables
    public Ellipse shape = new Ellipse();
    public Vector force = new Vector();
    public Vector velocity = new Vector();
    public Vector acceleration = new Vector();
    public Vector position = new Vector();
    #endregion
    public double Vector
    {
        get { return Math.Sqrt(velocity.X * velocity.X + velocity.Y * velocity.Y); }
    }
    public double Angle
    {
        get { return Math.Atan2(velocity.Y, velocity.X); }
    }
    public double radius
    {
        get { return shape.Width / 2; }
    }
    public double mass
    {
        get { return Math.PI * radius * radius; }
    }

    public KCircle()
    {
        initialize();
    }
    public void initialize()
    {
        color_normal();
        shape.StrokeThickness = 5;
        shape.Width = shape.Height = size;
    }

    public void change_color()
    {
        shape.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
        if (shape.Stroke == System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red)
        {
            shape.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
            return;
        }
        shape.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
    }
    public void color_normal()
    {
        shape.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        shape.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
    }
}

private void process_object_interactions(){
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.Count; i++)
        {
            KCircle a = circles[i];
            for (int z = i + 1; z < circles.Count; z++)
            {
                KCircle b = circles[z];
                if (collide(a, b)  )
                {
                    a.change_color();
                    b.change_color();

                    Vector d = distance_between(a, b);
                    double angle_n = Math.Atan2(d.Y, d.X);
                    double angle_t = angle_n + 90;
                    double direction_n = 1;
                    double direction_t = 1;
                    if (angle_n < 0)
                    {
                        angle_n += 360;
                    }

                    if (angle_n > 180)
                    {
                        direction_t = -1;
                    }
                    if (angle_n > 90 && angle_n < 270)
                    {
                        angle_t = angle_n - 90;
                        angle_n += 180;
                        direction_n = -1;
                    }
                    if (angle_n > 360)
                    {
                        angle_n -= 360;
                    }
                    KCircle[] c = new KCircle[2];
                    c[0] = a;
                    c[1] = b;
                    double[] direction_n_array = new double[2];
                    direction_n_array[0] = direction_n;
                    direction_n_array[1] = direction_n * -1;
                    double[] direction_t_array = new double[2];
                    direction_t_array[0] = direction_t;
                    direction_t_array[1] = direction_t * -1;
                    double[] velocity_t = new double[2];
                    double[] velocity_n = new double[2];

                    for (int v = 0; v < 2; v++)
                    {
                        double angle = Math.Abs(c[i].velocity.angle - angle_n);
                        velocity_n[v] =(direction_n_array[v]) * (c[v].velocity.magnitude() * Math.Cos(angle));
                        velocity_t[v] = (direction_t_array[v]) *(c[v].velocity.magnitude() * Math.Sin(angle));
                    }
                    Vector[] new_vector_n = new Vector[2];
                    Vector[] momentum = new Vector[2];
                    for (int v = 0; v < 2; v++)
                    {
                        new_vector_n[v] = new Vector(velocity_n[v] * Math.Cos(angle_n), (velocity_n[v] * Math.Sin(angle_n)));
                        momentum[v] = new_vector_n[v];
                        momentum[v] *= c[v].mass;
                    }
                    /**
                    velocity_n_new[0] = normal_velocity_exchange(velocity_n[0], velocity_n[1], c[0].mass, c[1].mass);
                    velocity_n_new[1] = normal_velocity_exchange(velocity_n[1], velocity_n[0], c[1].mass, c[0].mass);
                     * */
                    for (int v = 0; v < 2; v++)
                    {
                        c[v].velocity.X = velocity_t[v] * Math.Cos( angle_t);
                        c[v].velocity.Y = -1* ((velocity_t[v] )* Math.Sin(angle_t)) ;
                    }
                    c[0].velocity += momentum[1] * (1 / c[0].mass);
                    c[1].velocity += momentum[0] * (1 / c[1].mass);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the error(s) you are encountering?  It would affect what debugging strategy is optimal.

Comment: can you give us the implementation of KCircle and Vector?

Comment: Its wpf.program just stops and thats how i know i amgetting an error

Comment: Sure i will post them real soon

Comment: Done posting Kcircle and Vector class

Comment: Any reason you are not using the built-in Vector (System.Windows.Vector)?

Comment: Did not know but...seems like an excellemt idea

Comment: They do work but randomly gets an errr btw

Comment: So it seems i cover some colliding cases but not all...

Comment: what type is the object circles and what does it's class look like ... and what does method collide look like?

Comment: @user1143720 You keep on saying "get an error" - That is not a good problem description. You need to be more specific what kind of error (exception, crash?).

Comment: Circles is a list of kcircles and collode checks whether they collide by comparing sum of radius of two circles. If the distance between the two circles is smaller than the sum then they collide

Comment: I really have no idea. Wpf form does not say what type of an error is? I think? Or is there other way to do it?

Comment: @user1143720, WPF programs don't just stop.  Do you mean it hangs and becomes unresponsive?  What's speficially happening?  Also have you checked the corner conditions for process_object_interactions()?  I'm not a trig person, but what happens if angle is -450?  Shouldn't you be using a modulus operator instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the question that has been asked.

1. How to fix the code to operate correctly?
2. How to use the Visual Studio debugger?

This answer will address the second question.

First run the program in debug mode from Visual Studio. If there is an entry in a toolbar along the top that says Release, pull it down and change it to Debug.  Click the green triangle to start the program.

When an error is encountered Visual Studio should display the Exception Assistant Dialog Box as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ww37f14.aspx

What is the title of this dialog? It should say what type of exception was encountered.

In the Actions section click on View Detail to see more information about the exception.

Expand the details and find the Stack Trace. Pull down the Stack Trace on the right side to expand it.  The top line of the Stack Trace will tell you which line of source code caused the error and what the sequence of method calls was before that.

Use this basic debug information to help determine what the problem is or use it to add more specific error information to your question.